# Cant extract br text (beautifulSoup) python web scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to extract address from the below html source in "br" at the end, but I am unable to extract and dont know what to give as the attributes. I am using below code to extract the address but it doesn't work as expected. Any help is much appreciated.

Edit: I have copied the missing parts of the code in the below.

Full Source code:

```
[<div class="card dl">
 <span id="section-1"></span>
 <div class="card-header pb-1 px-1"><!-- Betriebsname -->
 <h3 class="card-title mb-0">
 <!-- <img src="https://www.tk-aerztefuehrer.de/TK/images/EntryType_person1.svg" alt=" " /> &nbsp;-->Praxis Dr. Christina Balduhn </h3>
 <!-- ***** HINWEIS PRIVAT ***** -->
 <!-- ************************** -->
 </div>
 <div class="card-body px-1"><!--  panel-body - einzelne Eintrag anfang   -->
 <div class="row">
 <div class="col-sm-5">
 <strong><a href="https://www.tk-aerztefuehrer.de/TK/Suche_SN/index.js?a=DD&amp;sid=&amp;e_id=830057&amp;Db=" style="text-decoration:underline;" title="Details zum Eintrag ansehen">Frau Dr. med. Christina Balduhn</a></strong>
 <br/><span style="color:#666;">Fachärztin für Allgemeinmedizin</span>
 <!--  ********
 <br /><br><span style="color:#7fb7c4; font-weight:700;">Praxis jetzt geöffnet</span>
 
 
 
 <p class="mt-3">Telefon: <a href="tel:+4952531717" class="it">0 52 53 / 17 17</a></p>
 
 **********  -->
 <br/>
 <!-- Fachgebiet:<br>Allgemeinmedizin<br><br />  -->
 <!-- ********* ArztImage Neu ******* -->
 <!-- ************** ArztImage Neu e ************* -->
 </div><!--  #sm-5 end  -->
 <div class="col-sm-4">
 <!--  ***********************************************  -->
 <div class="d-none d-md-block">
 <a class="btn btn-outline-secondary arrow-r" href="https://www.tk-aerztefuehrer.de/TK/Suche_SN/index.js?a=DD&amp;sid=&amp;e_id=830057&amp;Db=" title="Zur Detailseite">Zur Detailseite</a>
 <!-- OTB Termin finden desktop  **** -->
 <!-- ***  -->
 </div>
 <!-- <img class="mapicons" src="https://www.tk-aerztefuehrer.de/TK/images/GoogleImages/A.png" alt=" " /><br>  -->
 <!--  *********
 <br>
 <img src="https://www.tk-aerztefuehrer.de/TK/img/entfernung.svg" alt=" " />  0.2 km<br />
 <br>
 
 
 
 Tegelhof 1<br />
 33014 Bad Driburg<br />
 <br />
 *********  -->
 <p class="show-xs show sm"></p>
 </div><!--  #sm-4 end  -->
 <div class="col-sm-3">
 <!-- ###################################################
 <div>
 <a class="btn btn-primary" title="Details zum Eintrag ansehen" href="">Details zum Eintrag</a>
 </div>
 
 <div style="margin:1em 0;">
 <a class="btn btn-default" title="Bewertung geben" href="https://www.tk-aerztefuehrer.de/TK/Arzt-Auskunft/Suche_SN/index.js?a=FR&e_id=830057&db=">Bewertung geben</a>
 </div>
 
 
 <span class="empf-0" title="Noch keine Bewertung(en) vorhanden">&nbsp;0 Bewertung(en)</span>
 ############################
 
 <div style="margin: 0 0 1em 0;">
 <a style="width:70%;" class="btn btn-primary" title="Bewertung geben" href="https://www.tk-aerztefuehrer.de/TK/Suche_SN/index.js?a=FR&e_id=830057&db=">Bewertung geben <i class="fa fa-angle-right" style="padding-left:1.1em;"></i></a>
 </div>
 
 ################################################  -->
 <!-- Bewertungstatus (1-5 Punkte)  -->
 <img src="https://www.tk-aerztefuehrer.de/TK/img/rategrade-0.png" title="Keine Bewertungen vorhanden"/>
 <br/>
 <span class="empf-0" title="Noch keine Bewertung(en) vorhanden">0 Bewertung(en)</span>
 <!--  ***********************  OTB  ******************
 ******************************************  -->
 </div><!-- sm-3 end -->
 </div><!--   end row -->
 <div class="row"><!-- Eintrag End - Abstand zw. Einträge -->
 <div class="col-sm-12">
 <!--  ************  OTV  *************  -->
 <!--  ******** 
 <!--  ************  OTV e  *************  -->
 </div><!-- sm-12 end -->
 </div><!--   end row  -->
 <!--  2020 A  -->
 <!--     ###########  Row 2 ################# -->
 <div class="row">
 <div class="col-sm-5 py-2">
 <br/><span style="color:#7fb7c4; font-weight:600;">Praxis jetzt geöffnet</span>
 <p class="mt-5 d-none d-md-block">Telefon: <a class="it" href="tel:+4952531717">0 52 53 / 17 17</a></p>
 </div><!-- sm-5 end -->
 <div class="col-sm-4 pt-2">
 <!-- <img class="mapicons" src="https://www.tk-aerztefuehrer.de/TK/images/GoogleImages/A.png" alt=" " /><br>  -->
 <br/>
 <img alt=" " src="https://www.tk-aerztefuehrer.de/TK/img/entfernung.svg"/>  0.2 km<br/>
 <span class="pt-3 d-none d-md-block"></span>
 Tegelhof 1<br/>
 33014 Bad Driburg<br/>
 </div><!-- sm-4 end -->
 <div class="col-sm-3">
 </div><!-- sm-3 end -->
 </div><!--   end row  -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The html you posted is broken. You have html tags inside incomplete comments. Everything after <!-- ********* is invalid. I don't think this will work until that line is removed. If you initiate BeautifulSoup on that html block, it will not include the text you're trying to obtain. But it will if you remove the incomplete comment. If you don't have access to edit this webpage, you could treat the html as a string and replace the <!-- ********* with nothing, and then reference the fixed html string in BeautifulSoup.

There is probably a better way to do this, but this will get the information you want by referencing the previous, closest tag *img* and using that as an anchor to find the address text.

```
addressLine1 = str(soup.find('img', class_='').findNextSibling(text=True).findNextSibling(text=True).findNextSibling(text=True)).strip()
# Am Rathausplatz 4
addressLine2 = str(soup.find('img', class_='').findNextSibling(text=True).findNextSibling(text=True).findNextSibling(text=True).findNextSibling(text=True)).strip()
# 33014 Bad Driburg
```

Full example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# remove <!-- *********
html = """<div class="d-none d-md-block">
 <a class="btn btn-outline-secondary arrow-r" href="https://www.tk-aerztefuehrer.de/TK/Suche_SN/index.js?a=DD&amp;sid=&amp;e_id=799433&amp;Db=" title="Zur Detailseite">Zur Detailseite</a>
 <!-- OTB Termin finden desktop  **** -->
 <!-- ***  -->
 </div>
 <!-- <img class="mapicons" src="https://www.tk-aerztefuehrer.de/TK/images/GoogleImages/E.png" alt=" " /><br>  -->
 <br>
 <img src="https://www.tk-aerztefuehrer.de/TK/img/entfernung.svg" alt=" " />  0.3 km<br />
 <br>

 Am Rathausplatz 4<br />
 33014 Bad Driburg<br />
 <br />"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')  # if you use html.parser the code below will be different

# find <img> element first, then get text element next to it
addressLine1 = str(soup.find('img', class_='').findNextSibling(text=True).findNextSibling(text=True).findNextSibling(text=True)).strip()
# Am Rathausplatz 4
addressLine2 = str(soup.find('img', class_='').findNextSibling(text=True).findNextSibling(text=True).findNextSibling(text=True).findNextSibling(text=True)).strip()
# 33014 Bad Driburg

print(addressLine1)
print(addressLine2)
```

Comment: Sorry about that, my mistake I haven't copied the full code. Now I have updated it. I have also tried the above code by giving the class but it gives me an error as:  ```raise AttributeError(
   2174             "ResultSet object has no attribute '%s'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?" % key
   2175         )

AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?```

Comment: If you run the code that I posted using python 3.x it will run successfully and output the address.

Comment: The html code is still broken. There are comments and quotes that are not closed. The html is just really bad due errors and not following best practice for readability. No indents, bad comments, bad spacing.

The unclosed quote found at Db=" title="Zur Detailseite" and the unclosed comment <!--  ********* will make beautifulsoup not read the html correctly.

Comment: Hi, I looked carefully at the html code and found more lines of the code below the previous code I copied. I found more lines with the address. It looks like in a proper format. Could you please take a look at it. If this code helps to solve my problem. Many thanks in advance!!

Comment: From the above html code I tried to extract br tags using ```y =  soup.find('div', {"class": "col-sm-4 pt-2"})```  and got the results below ```<div class="col-sm-4 pt-2">
<!-- <img class="mapicons" src="https://www.tk-aerztefuehrer.de/TK/images/GoogleImages/A.png" alt=" " /><br>  -->
<br/>
<img alt=" " src="https://www.tk-aerztefuehrer.de/TK/img/entfernung.svg"/>  0.2 km<br/>
<span class="pt-3 d-none d-md-block"></span>
Tegelhof 1<br/>
33014 Bad Driburg<br/>
</div>``` but I am unable to extract specifically br tags.

Comment: Try using .get_text(). Add it to your soup.find call. Also, your html is still broken. Copy paste your code through a validator like https://www.freeformatter.com/html-validator.html. You have unclosed tags, unclosed comments, and nested comments. You can tell it's broken HTML even from looking at it here by how your html code switches to all green due to an unclosed comment tag on line 5. You need to take a much closer look at your html code.

Comment: Yes you are right, the html code is broken, It weird how this works. But I really thank you so much for your time!